# Show image on ImageView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have stored image uri on sqlite database and now i want to upload it to ImageView but my photo doesn't show.
Below my code sheets:

Store image

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE){
            local_profile_image.setImageURI(data?.data)
            // Add image to DB
            val usrLogin = intent.getStringExtra("UserLogin")
            val dbHandler = UserDBHelper(this, null)
            var res : Boolean = dbHandler.addUserImage(data?.data.toString(),usrLogin)
            if(res) Toast.makeText(this, "User image add to DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            // ... //
        }
    }
```

Following, you can see how I sav image uri on database

```
fun addUserImage(imgPath:String,userLogin:String) : Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(COLUMN_LOGIN,userLogin)
        values.put(USR_PROFILE_IMAGE,imgPath)
        db.insert(USR_PROFILE_TAB,null,values)
        if(!imgPath.isEmpty() && !userLogin.isEmpty()) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Than I fetch image from table using code below:

```
fun getUserImage(login: String): String? {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $USR_PROFILE_TAB WHERE $COLUMN_LOGIN = ?"
        db.rawQuery(selectQuery, arrayOf(login)).use { // .use requires API 16
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val usrImgUri : String = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(USR_PROFILE_IMAGE))
                return usrImgUri
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

After fetch image I want to set it on ImageView on different activity in onCreate method, but image doesn't show.

```
        val ivUserPhoto = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.local_profile_image)
        val usrGalleryPhoto = intent.getStringExtra("UsrImage")
        if (usrGalleryPhoto == null) {
            ivUserPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_crop_original_black_24dp)
        } else {
            val img_file = File(usrGalleryPhoto)
            val img_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_file.path)
            Toast.makeText(this, img_file.absolutePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() 
            ivUserPhoto.setImageBitmap(img_bmp)
   }
```

What I do wrong ? Help me, please. I am newbie in Kotlin and have started work with in recently.
Thank's a lot.
Denys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use just:

```
ivUserPhoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse("usrGalleryPhoto"))
```

Comment: I have tried this before, but my image didn't show.

Comment: also how you ar passing URI to Inent? you should use imageUri.toString() and pass it as a string, then reparse it to URI

Comment: yes I have shown what contains uri using Toast. I have slow laptop and don't have ability to test mu code on emulator. My uri object has path like "contents://..." I have compered this path with path of photo from gallery and their is not equal. I will try using Intent and share my result.

Comment: recently I have tried using ivUserPhoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse("usrGalleryPhoto")). My application didn't crash but the image didn't show. Maybe I made mistake on ImageView code ?

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/local_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_crop_original_black_24dp"  />

Comment: Maybe problem with lmageView size. How can I set it depence with image size ? @Antonis Radz

Comment: it should not be because  of the size, try to set image from resources, if that works then it should also work from uri. Also you can try to do with file like tried before just use this code `Uri.parse(imageUriString).toFile()` secret it `.toFile()` kotlin extension

Comment: @Antonis Radz, Android Studio doesn't find method toFile() when I wrote Uri.parse(imageUriString).toFile(). My app doesn't compile. Maybe I should use some specific libraries ?

Comment: When i use
`
           val imgUri : Uri = Uri.parse(usrGalleryPhoto)
            ivUserPhoto.setImageURI(imgUri)
`
my app crashes.

Comment: check stack trace why it is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Today I have tested my app on different device and I have got surprise.ImageView have show my profile image which I have store before through setImageURI(). I use Android 10 on my smartphone but application work fine on Android 9 device. I will open issue for Kotlin support team.